# How to define launch configuration using pip.exe

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to debug with the Python debugging the following command line run "pip install -e python" (started in the working directory of my project), so I'm trying to set up something like the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "PIP install",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "python",
            "program": "C:/ProgramData/miniconda3/envs/pytorch/Scripts/pip.exe",
            "args": ["install", "-e", "python"]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I need to run an exe but debug the python code (pip.exe will in turn run my python/setup.py file).

Is there any way to setup this in VSCode ?

(The above config doesn't work, if I set type="python" VSCode will run something like python.exe -- pip.exe install -e python)